# sdk: go back action without navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

**I don't have have navigation bar**, when I go from view 1 to view 2, there is a back button in view; When I click the back button in view 2, it go back to shows view 1 again.

- what is the best action in this case ?
- what is the possibility to change the button to an image ?

So anyone have suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still use a UINavigationController, but set the nav bar to be hidden.  The action of the button in view 2 should be [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES].  You can use the button's image property to make it an image.

Comment: thanks; but when I hide the nav bar I the button is hidden also !!

Comment: Yes, you will have to add your own button to view 2.